# Heroku Rails migration claims an existing column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

A migration that works on my local machine is failing on Heroku.  The error is as follows:

```
Migrating to ChangeTypeToCast (20131112072808)
==  ChangeTypeToCast: migrating ===============================================
-- add_column(:math_tests, :cast, :string)
   -> 0.1006s
-- add_column(:emotional_tests, :cast, :string)
   -> 0.1541s
-- remove_column(:math_tests, :type, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "string" of relation "math_tests" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "math_tests" DROP "string"/
```

The migration is removing a column that was created by an earlier migration.  The current and earlier migration are both listed below:

Creates the `type` column in the `math_tests` table

```
class CreateMathTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :math_tests do |t|
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Deletes `type` column in `math_tests` (Heroku fails on the first `remove_column` line)

```
class ChangeTypeToCast < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :math_tests, :cast, :string
    add_column :emotional_tests, :cast, :string
    remove_column :math_tests, :type, :string
    remove_column :emotional_tests, :type, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :math_tests, :cast, :string
    remove_column :emotional_tests, :cast, :string
    add_column :math_tests, :type, :string
    add_column :emotional_tests, :type, :string
  end
end
```

Why on earth is this happening?

Note: Running `heroku restart` and `heroku pg:reset` did not help

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked at the state of your table to see what it looks like?

Comment: There are a few ways. I use Rybymine to connect to the database and view the tables. To do that, go to your dashboard; click on your Postgres add-on; and you will see connection metadata. Configure the client of your choice with that information to do whatever you want with your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're running a different version of Rails than the Heroku instance is.

In some versions, you could specify the type of the column as you delete it, which allowed the removal of a column to be reversed. In others, you can specify which table to remove columns from, and then pass a list of column names to delete from. So, rather than trying to delete a column called 'type' of type 'string', it tries to delete a column 'type' as well as a column 'string'.

Relevant release notes - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record